# Is Beacon chain kept by all the validators in all the shards?

Tags: sharding, beacon-chain

In the most of current sharded blockchains, there is a second chain required for the computation needed for the maintenance of the whole of the network and receiving updates of the shards and their snapshots. Such a chain has different names in variant protocols: **Beacon chain (Ethereum 2.0)**, Relay chain (PolkaDot) etc.

So the second chain is used for keeping shards snapshots and maintenance of the network.

Is **Beacon chain** kept by **all** the validators in **all** the shards?

I mean is there **a copy** of the Beacon chain in **all** the shards such that **all** the validators has to maintain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there are beacon chain validators and shard validators.

All beacon chain validators would have the beacon chain.

A beacon chain validator would usually not be able to have all shards (they choose which shards to follow), since the purpose of sharding is so that a single validator doesn't have to validate all transactions in all shards.

Beacon chain validators for a particular shard, randomly get chosen to add the hash of the tip of the shard, to the beacon chain.  This hash is called a crosslink.

Comment: Can we say that for the Beacon chain (that is a single chain in the entire network) **"sharding of processing"** is done, but without **"sharding of storage" (state sharding)** ? That is, all Beacon validators have all the states of the Beacon chain, but each validator processes only a part of states. Is that correct (According to this article: https://medium.com/nearprotocol/the-authoritative-guide-to-blockchain-sharding-part-1-1b53ed31e060)? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. Your second sentence is clearer than the first, so I would explain in that order. Tweaking your second sentence to "each validator votes on the finality of only some shards" might also help explain.