# Beacon chain validators vs. Shard validators

Tags: sharding, beacon-chain

In the most of current sharded blockchains, there is a second chain required for the computation needed for the maintenance of the whole of the network and receiving updates of the shards and their snapshots. Such a chain has different names in variant protocols: **Beacon chain (Ethereum 2.0)**, Relay chain (PolkaDot) etc.

So the second chain is used for keeping shards snapshots and maintenance of the network.

According to this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72045/23024 :

> Beacon chain validators for a particular shard, randomly get chosen to
>   add the hash of the tip of the shard, to the beacon chain.

Does it mean that a **Beacon chain validator** CANNOT be a **shard validator** at the same time?

- If it is NOT permitted, **Why?**
- If it is permitted, **How?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Beacon Chain validator can also be a shard validator.

Recall, that initially there won't be any shards.

[State of Ethereum Protocol #2: The Beacon Chain](https://media.consensys.net/state-of-ethereum-protocol-2-the-beacon-chain-c6b6a9a69129) is a helpful article on these topics and describes that:

> validators participate in the protocol by proposing blocks, when chosen to do so, on both the Beacon Chain and, once they have been implemented, the shard chains.

---

To the question of how a Beacon Chain validator would also become a shard validator, the shard validation would probably be another piece of software and there would be APIs similar to [Beacon Node API for Validator](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/validator/0_beacon-node-validator-api.md), so that the Beacon Chain software and the shard chain software can communicate.

---

References:

- [Beacon Chain spec](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/core/0_beacon-chain.md)
- [State of Ethereum Protocol #2: The Beacon Chain](https://media.consensys.net/state-of-ethereum-protocol-2-the-beacon-chain-c6b6a9a69129)
- [Beacon Node API for Validator](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/validator/0_beacon-node-validator-api.md)
- [Ethereum 2.0 Specifications](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs)